# Link external pure javascript file to my React component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to build a react component with happy birthday animation written in an external javascript file. I know that we could link external javascript file by:

```
  componentDidMount() {
    const script = document.createElement("script");
    script.async = true;
    script.src = "./hbd.js";
    script.type = "text/javascript";
    this.div.appendChild(script);
  }
```

In the `hbd.js` javascript file I have a function `anim()` which I could call to display an animation.

However, if I don't change the type of script to `script.type = "text/bable "` or `script.type = "text/jsx "` it gives me an `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'` 
error. If I do change the types, no error is given but the file simply won't load, and no animation effect is seen.

Does someone out there know if it is possible at all to do that with React?

Comment: your server is most likely serving a 404 page to you. did you check network tab?

Comment: yes, when requesting my ```hbd.js``` file, it just strangely returns the react index.html file created by create-react-app.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you can `GET` the JavaScript file `hbd.js`. Point your browser to the full url and make sure that the hbd.js file is returned by the web server. If you have your web server locally, it would be something like `http://localhost/hbd.js`.